# SQL for ordering by number - 1,2,3,4 etc instead of 1,10,11,12

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I’m attempting to order by a number column in my database which has values 1-999

When I use

```
ORDER_BY registration_no ASC
```

I get….

```
1
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
11
110
Etc…
```

So it appears to be ordering by the first digit as oppose to the number.

Does anyone know what SQL to use if I want to order this by value? So `1,2,3,4,5,6` etc

Comment: Your column is of varchar type because of which you are facing this behavior.

Comment: what is the datatype of registration_no column?

Comment: Use `order by registration_no + 0 asc` to solve your problem.

Comment: You should **never** store numbers in a character column. Your problem is a direct result of that error.

Comment: My column is Varchar and the data I store is Class 10/Class 9/Class 8. Now class 10 comes before class 8. How do I solve this without having to do in for a display_order column?

Comment: To answer my own question.  One Blog suggested sorting by len(title), title to acheive a natural order sorting.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-sorting/

Answer (score 183):

One way to order by positive integers, when they are stored as `varchar`, is to order by the length first and then the value:

```
order by len(registration_no), registration_no
```

This is particularly useful when the column might contain non-numeric values.

Note:  in some databases, the function to get the length of a string might be called `length()` instead of `len()`.

Comment: This will not work in all cases. Off the top of head, cases that will not work are mixes of whole numbers with; negative numbers, numbers with leading zeros, numbers with fractions and words and numbers combined.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins . . . Read the first sentence of the answer.  I think it is quite clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is ordering by same column twice is not cpu and memory intensive ?

Comment: @Achyuth . . . The number of keys in an `order by` has little effect on performance.

Comment: Can you explain performance of this solution vs simply convert the string to integer as suggested in other answers?

Comment: @Luis . . . The performance is going to be pretty much the same, because the overhead is on the sort.  Type conversion and function calls both tend to preclude the use of indexes.  Avoiding type conversions eliminates one source of run-time errors.

Comment: For Oracle SQL, use `length()` instead of `len()`

Comment: How to implement the same on CodeIgniter? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 83):

```
ORDER_BY cast(registration_no as unsigned) ASC
```

explicitly converts the value to a number. Another possibility to achieve the same would be

```
ORDER_BY registration_no + 0 ASC
```

which will force an implicit conversation.

Actually you should check the table definition and change it. You can change the data type to `int` like this

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN registration_no int;
```

That way indexes can be used properly and the `order by` won't slow down the query.

Comment: ORDER BY ColumnName + 0 ASC
 works like a breeze. Thanks for this

Answer (score 16):

If you are using SQL Server:

```
ORDER_BY cast(registration_no as int) ASC
```

Answer (score 8):

```
ORDER_BY cast(registration_no as unsigned) ASC
```

gives the desired result with warnings.

Hence, better to go for

```
ORDER_BY registration_no + 0 ASC
```

for a clean result without any SQL warnings.

Comment: Can you explain why doing `+ 0` works? I've tested it on my data set and it, indeed, works, but I'm curious why? Does it convert it to a number before ordering?

Comment: Looks like when you do the + 0 the result of the return will take the data type of the argument with highest precedence. So when you do varchar+int , int has the highest precedence.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I cannot understand why this is not the most voted option, simple and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your column type is STRING (CHAR, VARCHAR, etc) and sorting procedure is sorting it  as a string. What you need to do is to convert value into numeric value. How to do it will depend on SQL system you use.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer doing a "PAD" to the data. MySql calls it LPAD, but you can work your way around to doing the same thing in SQL Server.

```
ORDER BY  REPLACE(STR(ColName, 3), SPACE(1), '0')
```

This formula will provide leading zeroes based on the Column's length of 3. This functionality is very useful in other situations outside of ORDER BY, so that is why I wanted to provide this option.

Results: 1 becomes 001, and 10 becomes 010, while 100 remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just don't have a choice about having to store numbers mixed with text. In one of our applications, the web site host we use for our e-commerce site makes filters dynamically out of lists. There is no option to sort by any field but the displayed text. When we wanted filters built off a list that said things like 
2" to 8"
9" to 12"
13" to 15" etc, we needed it to sort 2-9-13, not 13-2-9 as it will when reading the numeric values. So I used the SQL Server Replicate function along with the length of the longest number to pad any shorter numbers with a leading space. Now 20 is sorted after 3, and so on.

I was working with a view that gave me the minimum and maximum lengths, widths, etc for the item type and class, and here is an example of how I did the text.
(LB*n*Low and LB*n*High are the Low and High end of the 5 length brackets.)

```
REPLICATE(' ', LEN(LB5Low) - LEN(LB1High)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB1High) + '" and Under' AS L1Text,
REPLICATE(' ', LEN(LB5Low) - LEN(LB2Low)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB2Low) + '" to ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB2High) + '"' AS L2Text,
REPLICATE(' ', LEN(LB5Low) - LEN(LB3Low)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB3Low) + '" to ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB3High) + '"' AS L3Text,
REPLICATE(' ', LEN(LB5Low) - LEN(LB4Low)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB4Low) + '" to ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB4High) + '"' AS L4Text,
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), LB5Low) + '" and Over' AS L5Text
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is just because you have declared the column in CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT datatype. Just change the datatype to INT, BIGINT etc. This is will solved the problem of your custom ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is that datatype of registration_no is INT ;)

order by ´registration_no´ asc will work fine

Output: 1,2,3,4,5....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).