# Display numbers of rows you want

Tags: c#, sql, insert, grid

**Problem 1**: When you enters that he wants to enter n numbers of different records. C# creates that much number of rows and enters systematically.

For example:

```
Tbl1

    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | C1 | Ramesh   | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
    | C2 | Khilan   | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
    | C3 | kaushik  | Kota      |  2000.00 |
    | C4 | Chaitali | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
    | C5 | Hardik   | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
    | C6 | Komal    | MP        |  4500.00 |
    | C7 | Muffy    | Indore    | 10000.00 |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

When program ask enter numbers of data you want to ask. If you enters three then it creates dynamic textbox which enters all the records.

Data Table should be like this.....

```
  Tbl1
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | C1 | Ramesh   | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
    | C2 | Khilan   | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
    | C3 | kaushik  | Kota      |  2000.00 |
    | C4 | Chaitali | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
    | C5 | Hardik   | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
    | C6 | Komal    | MP        |  4500.00 |
    | C7 | Muffy    | Indore    | 10000.00 |
    | C8 | Hari     | Goa       |  8550.00 |
    | C9 | Aum      | Panjab    |  4500.00 |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

So overall for this problem I am asking is either C# creates dynamic text box in one line (For insert one row. textbox should be in online line. For Second in second line).

Or it loads the `GridView` table with previously entered data as well two rows to enter new records.

**Problem 2**: How to sort table in ascending order?

For example if I enter new record `C10 Ram Chennai  9000.00`
By default it comes under

```
 Tbl1
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | C1 | Ramesh   | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
    | C10| Ram      | Chennai   |  9000.00 |
    | C2 | Khilan   | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
    | C3 | kaushik  | Kota      |  2000.00 |
    | C4 | Chaitali | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
    | C5 | Hardik   | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
    | C6 | Komal    | MP        |  4500.00 |
    | C7 | Muffy    | Indore    | 10000.00 |
    | C8 | Hari     | Goa       |  8550.00 |
    | C9 | Aum      | Panjab    |  4500.00 |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

When sorting it should come under....

```
Tbl1
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
    | C1 | Ramesh   | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
    | C2 | Khilan   | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
    | C3 | kaushik  | Kota      |  2000.00 |
    | C4 | Chaitali | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
    | C5 | Hardik   | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
    | C6 | Komal    | MP        |  4500.00 |
    | C7 | Muffy    | Indore    | 10000.00 |
    | C8 | Hari     | Goa       |  8550.00 |
    | C9 | Aum      | Panjab    |  4500.00 |
    | C10| Ram      | Chennai   |  9000.00 |
    +----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Row C10 should come under C9. How to sort table?

Comment: Is the Id the primary key?

Comment: @Inanikian: Yes id is primary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this : `Select * From Tbl1 order by len(id), id`. you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16520873/3383479) which is very useful

Comment: Thank you it is working. But what about problem 1. I really need that one.