# sorting text which contains numbers?

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have field in database table which name is "number",table contain data like this

```
id number
1   1-1
2   2-4
3   10-1
4   7-1
```

when i sort this as "order by number" in query, it gives result like this,

```
id number
3   10-1
1   1-1
2   2-4
4   7-1
```

i want like this,

```
id number
1   1-1
2   2-4
4   7-1
3   10-1
```

i am using vb.net and my code is

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT number FROM TABLE_NAME order by number", cnn)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt
```

in which dgvData is datagridview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519648/sql-for-ordering-by-number-1-2-3-4-etc-instead-of-1-10-11-12

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the left part of the string to a number:

```
order by cast(left(number, charindex('-', number) - 1) as int)
```

Or, what works in many cases, including quite possibly yours, is to take the length into account:

```
order by len(number), number
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: You can do something like this, if the number after hyphen is always exactly 1 character.

```
ORDER BY RIGHT('0000'+number, 6)
```