# Ordering properties in MS SQL Server - including flats

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given a CAG and i'm trying to sort the address by Postcode and Building Number.  The problem i face is that Building Number is not actually integer, it's a nvarchar- because of flat properties.

You can see that 79B appears after 143:

```
131
133A
133B
135
137
139
141
143
79B <--
87 
89 
91
```

I have found a similar question:
[sql-for-ordering-by-number-1-2-3-4-etc-instead-of-1-10-11-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519648/sql-for-ordering-by-number-1-2-3-4-etc-instead-of-1-10-11-12)

and tried this

```
SQL += "ORDER BY BUILDNO * 1 ASC ";
```

but predictably i get a conversion error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '133A' to data type int.
```

Is it possible to order this type of nvarchar in SQL?

thanks

**UPDATE**

I know have this working, thanks @paYa

```
SELECT * FROM [" + tblname + "] 
WHERE POSTCODE LIKE + @postcode + '%' 
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT([BUILDNO], CASE WHEN PATINDEX(N'%[^0-9]%', [BUILDNO]) < 1 THEN LEN([BUILDNO]) ELSE PATINDEX(N'%[^0-9]%', [BUILDNO]) - 1 END) AS INT), 
RIGHT([BUILDNO], LEN([BUILDNO]) - PATINDEX(N'%[^0-9]%', [BUILDNO]) + 1)
```

returns the correct order:

```
79B
87 
89 
91 
133B
135
137
139
141
143
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @sgeddes Sorry, using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in mssql server

```
order by cast(left([ColName], case when patindex(N'%[^0-9]%', [ColName]) < 1 then len([ColName]) else patindex(N'%[^0-9]%', [ColName]) - 1 end) as int),
right([ColName], len([ColName]) - patindex(N'%[^0-9]%', [ColName]) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lpad with blank

in mysql

```
 ORDER BY lpad(your_column,  16 - length(your_column ), ' ')
```

in sqlserver

```
  ORDER BY right(replicate(' ',16 - length(your_column )) + YourFieldValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse Building Number, extract leading integer and all the rest. MS SQL:

```
select nbr
from ( values('79'),('100'),('79B') ) t(nbr)
cross apply (select pos = patindex('%[^0-9]%',nbr+'X')-1 ) x
order by cast(left(nbr, pos) as int)
    , substring (nbr, pos+1, 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `patindex` that basically strips the beginning numbers from the `varchar`.

```
select *
from yourtable 
order by left(id, patindex('%[a-z]%', id + 'A') - 1)
```

Similar solutions can be applied to other databases as well.