# MSSQL & PHP: Order by column only 2 digits? why?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have an SQL Statement for in my near search and a column with ORDER BY.

However, this orders only the first 2 Digits for example:

Order by column1 DESC

Data (sorted):

- 999 - 9920 -988 -977 -9729 -960 -950 -900 -890 -8912

**Here is my SQL:**

```
$sql_nearme = "SELECT  * FROM ( SELECT place.facebook_likes,place.place_logo, place.place_rank, place.percent_points, place.points, place.place_id, place.place_adress, place.place_description, place.place_photo, place.place_name,(6371 * acos(cos(radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].")) * cos(
              radians(place.place_lat)
                ) * cos(
                    radians(place.place_long) - radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'].")
                ) + sin(
                    radians(".$map['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].")
                ) * sin(
                    radians(place.place_lat)
                )
            )
        ) AS distance
FROM place) A WHERE A.distance < 100 ORDER BY facebook_likes DESC OFFSET ".$blatt_start." ROWS FETCH NEXT ".$blatt_end." ROWS ONLY";
```

Comment: Is the column a `varchar` by chance? That would sort it differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL for ordering by number - 1,2,3,4 etc instead of 1,10,11,12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519648/sql-for-ordering-by-number-1-2-3-4-etc-instead-of-1-10-11-12)

Comment: Thanks yes the column was a varchar now int. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause as below:

```
FROM place) A WHERE A.distance < 100 ORDER BY 
  try_convert(int,Right(convert(varchar(10),facebook_likes),2)) DESC OFFSET ".$blatt_start." ROWS FETCH NEXT ".$blatt_end." ROWS ONLY";
```