# jdbc sql 'weird' data sorting

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i have these String data in this order in my database : 07.00 , 09.00, 11.00, 13.00, 15.00, 17.00.

when i take the data from the sql and put it in Java the output become like this 
11.00, 13.00, 15.00, 17.00, 07.00 09.00.

basically in put it in the lowest first number order, is there any way to get it in the order i want ?

Here's my code :

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver());
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Project","root","root");
statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
resultset = statement.executeQuery(" SELECT DISTINCT departtime FROM book WHERE departfrom = '" + fromcmbtxt + "'");

while(resultset.next()){
     System.out.println(resultset.getString("departtime");
}
```

Comment: Post the java code for sorting

Comment: Remember that databases don't usually have an explicit and consistent order. If you're not using `SORT BY`, you can't guarantee anything about the results being returned.

Comment: @mallikarjun i'm not doing any sorting using the java code.

Comment: @Kayaman that is in 'order' according to database, so even if i use DESC it will just reverse it in that order

Comment: @KevinGuswanto Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519648/sql-for-ordering-by-number-1-2-3-4-etc-instead-of-1-10-11-12) help

Comment: I meant that the database is free to return the data in any order it wants to, if you're not specifying a `SORT BY`. But since your values don't really have a natural order, you'd have to use some sort of order column.

Comment: @KevinGuswanto as Kayaman mentioned you have to do the "Order BY" in your query or you have to use a custom compactor to get the desired order in the java side.

Comment: @AnkurSinghal it does, works like a charm, post it as an answer and i will accept it, thank you !

Comment: @KevinGuswanto Thanks, it worked for you, posting same answer again is not a good idea, rather should be marked as duplicate of the same.

Comment: So you *didn't* want the `08:00` to be the last?

Comment: @Kayaman my bad, sorry. the 08:00 wasn't suppose to be there